# asp.net webforms - how to get the json data of a javascript function using c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, webforms

I have a function in my `javascript` that returns a `json`. I want to get the return value of that javascript function using c# so I can convert it in dataTable. Can anyone help me? Sorry I'm just a beginner in asp.net webforms.

**JS**

```
function getAllMessages()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/Messages/',
            contentType: 'application/html ; charset:utf-8',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'JSON'
        }).success(function (result) {

        });
    }
```

Comment: "I want to get the return value of that javascript function using c#". What does this mean?, Do you want to send an ajax call to C# and get JSON?

Comment: the javascript function `getAllMessages()` return a `json` and I want to get it using c# function. The c# function will convert the json to dataTable.

Comment: Can you share the C# code as well?

Comment: sorry I don't have the c# code yet coz I'm trying to figure out how can I get the return value of that javascript function :( I tried to pass the json in `input text` and get it in `Page_Load` but I got nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you don't have the actual code , i'll just give an algorithm. I experienced this scenario in one of my projects.

In your html/asp.net button, execute a webmethod that has a parameter to receive the json format

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'YourPage.aspx/c#MethodThatWillReceiveJSON',
            data: "{c#MethodParameterName:" + JSON.stringify(YourJSONvalues) + "}",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (r) {
                alert(r.d.exampleDataFromJson);

            }
        });
```

You need to create another javascript function that will call your original javascript (The one who will return the json format) and use that function to pass it as an argument to the parameter of your c# webmethod.

```
//your original javascript function that returns json
  function getJsonData()
  {
   // your code
  }

  // use that js function to store in a var , then pass it to your c#
   var MyJSONdata = getJSONData();
   $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'YourPage.aspx/c#MethodThatWillReceiveJSON',
        data: "{c#MethodParameterName:" + JSON.stringify(MyJSONdata) + "}",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (r) {
            alert(r.d.exampleDataFromJson);

        }
    });
```

If you use a String type as a parameter in your c# webmethod, you can not use/manipulate it as a json stuff, you need to convert your String variable using json serializer :) which you can find a lot of reference here in net/stackoverflow, it is just one liner of code to convert. :)

Comment: thank you for your reply @Francis Saul I will going to try your code :)